# VS Installer - Change Theme?

Tags: visual-studio, vsinstaller

I recently installed VS Installer extension to create an installer for my produce. I saw at the forums that VS Installer has a dark theme to select.
But how do I change the theme? My current installer has a white theme.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Click the moon/sun symbol on the top right.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It seems like I can't find that symbol, where its supposed to be?

Comment: Hold on, are you talking about the Visual Studio installer or a Installer for a Program that Visual Studio offers?

Comment: im talking about hat, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects